# Unable to remove local login for linked server

Tags: ssms, linked-server, logins

I have added a linked server that was working fine. After this I added a local login to within properties > security on the linked server. After doing this I get an error when trying to run a query using this link stating:

> access to remote server is denied because no login-mapping exists sql

I tried removing the local login and although I can use the remove option and select OK if I load up the properties again the user remains. How can I permanently remove this user?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is related to linked server connection security.
If you do not map any logins with a specific SQL Server account, you can select the `Be made using this security context` option and specify a SQL Server account with the following syntax:

```
EXEC sp_addlinkedsrvlogin 'TEST1', 'false', 'userLocal', 'userRemote', 'remotePassword'
```

As alternative solution you can use the parameter `@datasrc` instead of `@provstr`. `@dataSrc` should works without setting the `User ID`

Example:

```
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver @server = N'LinkServerName', @provider=N'SQLNCLI',@srvproduct = 'MS SQL Server', @datasrc=N'serverName\InstanceName' 

EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedsrvlogin @rmtsrvname = N'LinkServerName', @locallogin = NULL , @useself = N'False', @rmtuser = N'myUser', @rmtpassword = N'*****'
```